# Storing SQL Select result into String Variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to store the result from my SQL query into a `string` variable. This is what I have:

```
  string strName = dt.Rows[i][name].ToString();
  string selectBrandID = "SELECT [Brand_ID] FROM [myTable] WHERE [real_name] = '" + strName + "'";

  using (SqlCommand sqlCmdSelectBrandID = new SqlCommand(selectBrandID, sqlConn))
        {
           sqlCmdSelectBrandID .Connection.Open();
           using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCmdSelectBrandID.ExecuteReader())
                 {
                      if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                           reader.Read();
                           string newBrandID = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Brand_ID"));
                        }
                       sqlCmdSelectBrandID.Connection.Close();
                 }
        }
```

This currently throws the exception `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.` On `string newBrandID =reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Brand_ID"));`  line.

Any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `Brand_ID` is stored in an integer field, then you should keep it as an integer. The GetString fails because the underlying field is not a string, you could simply use the GetInt32 (see the [SqlDataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader(v=vs.110).aspx) docs)

```
int newBrandID = reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("Brand_ID"));
```

Then, if for whatever purpose you want it as a string, it is just a matter to apply the `ToString()` method to your integer

```
string brandID = newBrandID.ToString();
```

Comment: Ok, so now it is stored and then I just tried to use the variable in an insert statement to place in a sql table and it says "newBrandID doesn't exist in the current context". How can I make that global?

Comment: Could you simply return it from this code and pass to the other method? Globals are always a necessary evil. If you could avoid them.... otherwise just declare the newBrandID at the class level

Comment: Or, if the insert is following this same block of code, move the declaration of newBrandID at the same level of the strName

Comment: Can you show me an example of what you're talking about exactly in your answer?

Comment: Weird thing is, is that they are in the same IF statement

Comment: If you want the newBrandID available to all methods of your class move its declaration (`int newBrandID;`) just after the brace following the `public class xxxxx` line. If you want it to be used inside the current method, then move the declaration just before the `string strName ....` line